# Не работает скрипт после подгрузки ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

jQuery.ScrollTo перемотка скролла вызывается этим скриптом:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.bp-pager').click(function() {
    jQuery.scrollTo('#wrapper');
});
});
```

Но после того как происходит ajax подгрузка, он перестает работать. Я прочитал что надо добавить обработчик событию, но я не разбираюсь в этом подскажите как правильно написать

Попробовал вот так

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.bp-pager').live("click", function(){
    jQuery.scrollTo('#wrapper');
});
});
```

вообще перестало работать.

**Ответ:**

```
$('.db_wrapper').on('click', '.bp-pager', function(){ 
jQuery.scrollTo('#wrapper'); });
```

**.db_wrapper** это блок который оборачивает содержимое подгружаемое ajax

с решением помог Dmitry только с body не сработало.

Comment: Непонятно как `ajax` связан с проблемой. Скорее всего, `ajax` запросом загружается html контент, который заменяет оригинальный html, на который вы устанавливаете обработчик события `click`. Попробуйте так `jQuery('body').on("click", ".bp-pager", function(){   jQuery.scrollTo('#wrapper'); });`

Comment: Нет, так не работает. Вы правильно поняли Ajax подгружает контент внутри которого и находятся bp-pager

Comment: Вот так сработало  $('.db_wrapper').on('click', '.bp-pager', function(){
    jQuery.scrollTo('#wrapper');
});

Comment: .db_wrapper это блок который оборачивает  содержимое подгружаемое ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ:

```
$('.db_wrapper').on('click', '.bp-pager', function(){ 
jQuery.scrollTo('#wrapper'); });
```

**.db_wrapper** это блок который оборачивает содержимое подгружаемое ajax

Answer (score 0):

1.Подгружай `jquery` скрипт через `async`:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/js/file"></script>
```

2. Если функция не срабатывает через `jQuery(document).ready()` закинь функцию на загрузку в `body`:

```
<body onload="yourFunction()">
    //Content
</body>
```